# How can I make the sum of 3 number picker 100?

Tags: java, android, numberpicker, android-number-picker

I want to make an application with 3 number pickers. I want to find the percentage distribution of carbohydrates, fat and protein. and this 3 number picker works in coordination with each other and I want to adjust the max and min values ​​accordingly. The sum of these 3 number pickers will be 100. e.g; like 15,35,50 or 50.45.5 or 10,20,70

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfdMI.jpg)

```
        NumberPicker carb=add_dialog.findViewById(R.id.carb);
        NumberPicker protein=add_dialog.findViewById(R.id.protein);
        NumberPicker fat=add_dialog.findViewById(R.id.fat);

        carb.setMinValue(1);
        carb.setMaxValue(99);
        protein.setMinValue(1);
        protein.setMaxValue(99);
        fat.setMinValue(1);
        fat.setMaxValue(99);

        // Initial
        carb.setValue(25);
        protein.setValue(40);
        fat.setValue(35);


        carb.setOnValueChangedListener((picker, oldVal, newVal) -> {
            protein.setMaxValue(100-(newVal+fat.getValue()));
            fat.setMaxValue(100-(newVal+protein.getValue()));
        });
```

Comment: If you will try using onValueChange event of any sort (not sure there is one but I'm speaking in general) you'll get stackOverFlow Exception as each change will drag 2 changes that will drag 2 more each and so on and on until you stack is full. Best approach would be, imo, set an "active" pointer to the number picker that was changed and upon pressing a button / applying the change in any way you see fit, you'll change the values of the other numbers according to your logic

Comment: Do you want the maximums adjusted, or do you want the three quantities to always sum to 100? In either case, if the pickers are at maximum and one is increased, how should the others be adjusted?

Comment: Hello to everyone who commented, I am the owner of the topic, but I had to write with my old account because I could not enter my e-mail address. (this account was closed for asking questions) @DanBaruch

Comment: I think I can't make a listener for each number picker. and with each number picker, another two will be triggered, so that the sum of the three will be 100. For example, the first number picker will increase as 50,51,52,53, while the minimum value of the other two number pickers will be reduced until its minimum value is one.. I hope I have been able to explain. so at the end of everything this 3 number picker sum will be 100

Comment: Yes but you can't know which picker to reduce. You have picker A,B and C. If you change A's value, do you change B's or C's value to match it? That's your business logic. In anyway, I'd recommend having a button pressed doing all the magic, unless you want you logic to apply to a single picker effecting the other 2 pickers, in which you can use some sort of onValueChanged event.